# Calculation of Jacobians for a finite element method simulation

Tags: vector-calculus

I'm attempting to calculate symbolic expressions for the (Newton's method) Jacobian of a Galerkin finite element method using Mathematica. It would seem that this is a perfect application for symbolic differentiation tools but I can't get it working (probably due to my lack of Mathematica knowledge).

## Mathematical statement of the problem

Let $v(\mathbf{x})$ and $\psi_k(\mathbf{x})$ ($k=1,\ldots,N$) be simple(ish) polynomial functions of space. Let $\mathbf{m}(\mathbf{x}) = [m_1(\mathbf{x}),m_2(\mathbf{x}),m_3(\mathbf{x})] $ be a vector field.

Let
$$
\mathbf{m}(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{k=1}^N \psi_k(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{m}_k,
$$
and
$$
r(\mathbf{x}) = \int_V (\mathbf{m} \times \nabla^2 \mathbf{m}) v(\mathbf{x}) dV.
$$

(I have used $\nabla^2$ as the *vector* Laplacian
$
\nabla^2 \mathbf{m} = [ \nabla^2 m_1, \nabla^2 m_2, \nabla^2 m_3].
$)

Calculate $\frac{\partial r}{\partial m_{i,k}}$ for all $i$ (directions of $\mathbf{m}$), and all $k \in {1,\ldots,N}$ (index for the $\psi$ functions).

## My code

I'm sure this can be written much more elegantly but as I said before I'm not too great with Mathematica. Anyway it should be good enough to give you the idea.

```
psi[x_, y_, z_] := {a[x, y, z], b[x, y, z]};
(* Really we just need to declare that this is a vector somehow...*)

m[x_, y_, z_] := {m1x*psi[x, y, z][[1]] + m2x*psi[x, y, z][[2]],
  m1y*psi[x, y, z][[1]] + m2y*psi[x, y, z][[2]],
  m1z*psi[x, y, z][[1]] + m2z*psi[x, y, z][[2]]}

VectorLaplacian[f[x,y,z]_] := {
  D[f[x,y,z][[1]], {x, 2}] + D[f[x,y,z][[1]], {y, 2}] + D[f[x,y,z][[1]], {z, 2}],
  D[f[x,y,z][[2]], {x, 2}] + D[f[x,y,z][[2]], {y, 2}] + D[f[x,y,z][[2]], {z, 2}],
  D[f[x,y,z][[3]], {x, 2}] + D[f[x,y,z][[3]], {y, 2}] + D[f[x,y,z][[3]], {z, 2}]
}

r[x_, y_, z_] := (Cross[m[x, y, z], VectorLaplacian[m[x, y, z]]])*v[x,y,z]
 (* I've left out the integration for now to keep things simpler *)

J[x_, y_, z_] := {
  {D[r[x,y,z][[1]], m1x], D[r[x,y,z][[2]], m1x], D[r[x,y,z][[3]], m1x]},
  {D[r[x,y,z][[1]], m1y], D[r[x,y,z][[2]], m1y], D[r[x,y,z][[3]], m1y]},
  {D[r[x,y,z][[1]], m1z], D[r[x,y,z][[2]], m1z], D[r[x,y,z][[3]], m1z]},

  {D[r[x,y,z][[1]], m2x], D[r[x,y,z][[2]], m2x], D[r[x,y,z][[3]], m2x]},
  {D[r[x,y,z][[1]], m2y], D[r[x,y,z][[2]], m2y], D[r[x,y,z][[3]], m2y]},
  {D[r[x,y,z][[1]], m2z], D[r[x,y,z][[2]], m2z], D[r[x,y,z][[3]], m2z]}
}

J[1, 1, 1]
```

But all I get is:

```
{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

Comment: There are some syntax issues here. If you change all the terms like  psi[[1]][x, y, z] to psi[x, y, z][[1]] then at least it makes sense (this would be a[x,y,z]) in your example. Just making this change in the m[] definition gives values for r, i.e., you can ask for r[x,y,z] and you get something fairly large. The J function has a similar issue, perhaps m[[1]] should be m[x,y,z][[1]] (presumably you mean the first element of the polynomial m[x,y,z]).

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed those mistakes now but I'm still not getting a real answer.

Comment: @dshepherd, note that the definiton of your `VectorLaplacian` is not quite right. You may want to define a function and then test it to see if it works. e.g. evaluate `VectorLaplacian[m[x, y, z]]` to see that it does what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this for a specific N it is straightforward.

Let us load the calculus package.

```
<<VectorAnalysis`
```

For readability let us use the formatting rules

```
 Format[Subscript[\[Psi], a__][x, y, z]] = Subscript[\[Psi], a];
  Format[\[Nu][x, y, z]] = \[Nu];
```

Use cartesian coordinate for Laplacian and Cross product

```
  SetCoordinates[Cartesian[x, y, z]]
```

Let us define

```
 psi[k_][x_, y_, z_] = {Subscript[\[Psi], k, 1][x, y, z], Subscript[\[Psi], k, 2][x, y, z] , 
                     Subscript[\[Psi], k, 3][x, y, z] };
```

Now let's say we have `N=2` for the sake of this example;
Define

```
 m[x_, y_, z_] = Sum[psi[k][x, y, z]*{Subscript[m, 1, k], Subscript[m, 2, k], 
                 Subscript[m, 3, k]}, {k, 1, 2}];
```

Defining the integrant:

```
 rint = \[Nu][x, y, z] Cross[m[x, y, z], Map[Laplacian, m[x, y, z]]];
```

Now `mm` is the set of variables:

```
 mm = 
 Table[{Subscript[m, 1, k], Subscript[m, 2, k], Subscript[m, 3, 
 k]}, {k, 2}]
```

This table will be your 'Jacobian'

```
  jac=Map[D[rint, #] &, mm, {2}]; 
  jac // TableForm
```

If you want an expression for arbitrary N its also possible.

*EDIT*

You might want to consider the case where the fields `Subscript[m,i,k]` depends on `{x,y,z}` as well.

One should then add the formatting rule

```
Format[Subscript[m, a__][x, y, z]] = Subscript[m, a];
```

define

```
m[x_, y_, z_] = Sum[psi[k][x, y, z]*{Subscript[m, 1, k][x, y, z], 
              Subscript[m, 2, k][x, y, z], Subscript[m, 3, k][x, y, z]}, {k, 1, 2}]
```

And deal with derivatives by integration by part (subject to proper boundary conditions...); e.g.

```
Subscript[\[Psi], 1, 1][x, y, z] D[D[Subscript[m, 1, 1][x, y, z], {x,2}], 
Subscript[m, 1, 1][x, y, z]] -> D[Subscript[\[Psi], 1, 1][x, y, z], {x,2}]
```

Comment: Of course, these days, one loads ``<<VectorAnalysis` `` instead of the ``<<Calculus` `` context...

Comment: No point reminding me how old I am! :-)

Comment: Don't worry about it, it took me a while to get used to the new way they're doing add-on packages myself... :)

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up rechecking my solutions by hand and then forgot about this question. But it will definitely be useful later on so thank you very much :)